# How to forbid grounding of false facts in Answer Set Programming/Gringo

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo, gringo

When I run gringo on my program, it results into many grounded statements of the form

```
:- foo(a,b).
```

Then I also obtain many grounded constraints such as:

```
:- bar(a,x,y), foo(a,b).
```

Given the knowledge above, these are totally useless.

Note, these are both grounded versions of a rule in the following form:

```
:- foo(I, J), bar(I, X, B), quux(J, X, @f(B)).
```

Why are the grounded rules even present in the output? Why won't gringo just exclude `foo(a,b)` from the set of grounded atoms? Can I disable it somehow? The gringo output of my program is bloated by this and signifiacantly slows it down.

Comment: If I understand gringo correctly, the rule you've given will not generate the grounded constraints you've given, it will generate grounded constraints which are conjunctions of all three predicates, e.g.:

:- foo(a,b), bar(a,c,d), quux(b,c,e).

Do you have other rules generating those constraints?  Do I misunderstand gringo?

Comment: You understand correctly.

Comment: In which case you must have other rules generating those grounded constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `#show` directive to display only the results that you want to see e.g.,

```
#show foo/2.
#show bar/3.
```